# pyparsing Regex as Word

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm building a syntax parser to perform simple actions on objects identified using **dotted notation**, something like this:

```
DISABLE ALL;
ENABLE A.1 B.1.1 C
```

but in `DISABLE ALL` the keyword `ALL` is instead matched as 3 `Regex(r'[a-zA-Z]') => 'A', 'L', 'L'` I use to match arguments.

**How can I make a Word using regex? AFAIK I can't get `A.1.1` using Word**

please see example below

```
import pyparsing as pp

def toggle_item_action(s, loc, tokens):
    'enable / disable a sequence of items'
    action = True if tokens[0].lower() == "enable" else False
    for token in tokens[1:]:
        print "it[%s].active = %s" % (token, action)

def toggle_all_items_action(s, loc, tokens):
    'enable / disable ALL items'
    action = True if tokens[0].lower() == "enable" else False
    print "it.enable_all(%s)" % action

expr_separator = pp.Suppress(';')

#match A
area = pp.Regex(r'[a-zA-Z]')
#match A.1
category = pp.Regex(r'[a-zA-Z]\.\d{1,2}')
#match A.1.1
criteria = pp.Regex(r'[a-zA-Z]\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}')
#match any of the above
item = area ^ category ^ criteria
#keyword to perform action on ALL items
all_ = pp.CaselessLiteral("all")

#actions
enable = pp.CaselessKeyword('enable')
disable = pp.CaselessKeyword('disable')
toggle = enable | disable

#toggle item expression
toggle_item = (toggle + item + pp.ZeroOrMore(item)
    ).setParseAction(toggle_item_action)

#toggle ALL items expression
toggle_all_items = (toggle + all_).setParseAction(toggle_all_items_action)

#swapping order to `toggle_all_items ^ toggle_item` works
#but seems to weak to me and error prone for future maintenance
expr = toggle_item ^ toggle_all_items
#expr = toggle_all_items ^ toggle_item

more = expr + pp.ZeroOrMore(expr_separator + expr)

more.parseString("""
    ENABLE A.1 B.1.1;
    DISABLE ALL
    """, parseAll=True)
```

Comment: What happened to the other comments/answer? I thought they were useful to the discussion.

Comment: @Paul: there's a discussion on meta that complains about users with high reputation that delete their bad answers to avoid downvotes... ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the problem?

```
#match any of the above
item = area ^ category ^ criteria
#keyword to perform action on ALL items
all_ = pp.CaselessLiteral("all")
```

Should be:

```
#keyword to perform action on ALL items
all_ = pp.CaselessLiteral("all")
#match any of the above
item = area ^ category ^ criteria ^ all_
```

EDIT - if you're interested...

Your regexes are so similar, I thought I'd see what it would look like to combine them into one. Here is a snippet to parse out your three dotted notations using a single Regex, and then using a parse action to figure out which type you got:

```
import pyparsing as pp

dotted_notation = pp.Regex(r'[a-zA-Z](\.\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)?') 
def name_notation_type(tokens):
    name = {
        0 : "area",
        1 : "category",
        2 : "criteria"}[tokens[0].count('.')]
    # assign results name to results - 
    tokens[name] = tokens[0] 
dotted_notation.setParseAction(name_notation_type)

# test each individually
tests = "A A.1 A.2.2".split()
for t in tests:
    print t
    val = dotted_notation.parseString(t)
    print val.dump()
    print val[0], 'is a', val.getName()
    print

# test all at once
tests = "A A.1 A.2.2"
val = pp.OneOrMore(dotted_notation).parseString(tests)
print val.dump()
```

Prints:

```
A
['A']
- area: A
A is a area

A.1
['A.1']
- category: A.1
A.1 is a category

A.2.2
['A.2.2']
- criteria: A.2.2
A.2.2 is a criteria

['A', 'A.1', 'A.2.2']
- area: A
- category: A.1
- criteria: A.2.2
```

EDIT2 - I see the original problem...

What is messing you up is pyparsing's implicit whitespace skipping. Pyparsing will skip over whitespace between defined tokens, but the converse is not true - pyparsing does not require whitespace between separate parser expressions.  So in your all_-less version, "ALL" looks like 3 areas, "A", "L", and "L".  This is true not just of Regex, but just about any pyparsing class. See if the pyparsing WordEnd class might be useful in enforcing this.

EDIT3 - Then maybe something like this...

```
toggle_item = (toggle + pp.OneOrMore(item)).setParseAction(toggle_item_action)
toggle_all = (toggle + all_).setParseAction(toggle_all_action)

toggle_directive = toggle_all | toggle_item
```

The way your commands are formatted, you have to make the parser first see if ALL is being toggled before looking for individual areas, etc.  If you need to support something that might read "ENABLE A.1 ALL", then use a negative lookahead for `item`: `item = ~all_ + (area ^ etc...)`.
(Note also that I replaced `item + pp.ZeroOrMore(item)` with just `pp.OneOrMore(item)`.)

Comment: First of all thanks Paul for your great pyparsing, I have to keep things separated as some actions are allowed on `criterion` but not `area`or `category` and so on so I want to differentiate. `all_` can't be `^` with items as it's a way different parseAction. If you run my code above you get the wrong result but if you just uncomment line 42 you can see the correct result (as `ALL` is matched before `A` `L` `L`). Is this the only way to achieve this?

Comment: thank you very much, I now understand more about operands order (I was stick to logic `or` behavior) and also about `-` operand that ignored until now.

Comment: ehm... I was _stuck_, not _stick_ :D